# Calculating the gamble chance for correction on a multiple choice question with multiple answers usng negative marking

Tags: probability

I'm trying to figure out the following, and I can get some results but I would like some input from more knowledgeable people.

So I have a multiple choice with 8 total answers, 3 correct answers and 5 incorrect answers (actually these numbers are all variable and I'm looking for a formula to fit all if possible).

I will be using negative markings so every wrong answer will lower their score.

Say they normally have a score of 1, and for every incorrect answer points are subtracted. We don't want to reward an answer that has, for instance, more than 3 incorrect answers in it, so that would be the falloff point that 0 points are rewarded.

Now my question would be twofold. Should I even be using a correction value for guessing when using negative marking? And if so, what would be a way to deal with this? How would I calculate such a thing?

To clarify:
I'm trying to calculate how hard it is to guess the answers, and find some meaningful number I can use in my formula to calculate the actual score of the test. In order to calculate that I need to know first how to calculate the result of a single question.

So what are the odds to guess a multiple choice question with multiple answers correct. This number together with a proposed knowledge value will be used to calculate the score the user will actually get.

Now because I am using negative marking, I am still doubting if I need to use a guessing correction. I was hoping somebody here had some experience working with calculating scores on MC questions with multiple answers using negative markings might know the best deal way to deal with guessing.

Comment: What do you mean 'using a correction value' by the way?

Comment: I ment the gamble/guess correction that is applied to the question. Usually, in multiple choice questions they apply some kind of modifier to the score of the question. Basically it is: Formula scoring is a procedure designed to reduce multiple-choice test score irregularities due to guessing. Typically, a formula score is obtained by subtracting a proportion of the number of wrong responses from the number correct.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you are asking but here's the math I can figure out so far.

So suppose who have $n$ questions and the falloff threshold is $k$.

Each correct answer scores $a$ marks and each incorrect answer deducts $b$ marks.

Let $X$ denotes the number of correct answers. Suppose you have $c$ choices per question.

So we know that $X\sim\mathrm{B}\left(n,\frac{1}{c}\right)$ if the paper is completely randomly attempted.

Let $Y$ be the score for that test. So we have
$$Y=\begin{cases}aX-b(n-X) &\text{if } &X>k\\
0&\text{if } &X\leq k\end{cases}$$
This simplifies to
$$Y=\begin{cases}(a+b)X-bn &\text{if } &X>k\\
0&\text{if } &X\leq k\end{cases}$$

The maximum possible mark would obviously be $aX$.

The expected mark from a student that completely guessed the answers will be
\begin{align}
E(Y)&=\left(\sum_{i=k+1}^{n}{((a+b)X-bn)P(X=i)}\right)+0P(X\le k)\\
&=\sum_{i=k+1}^{n}{((a+b)X-bn)\binom{n}{i}\left(\frac{1}{c}\right)^i\left(1-\frac{1}{c}\right)^{n-i}}
\end{align}
which we can just use a software to compute since the exact value is not something we need here.

Comment: Thank you for your response, i've updated my original question.with more information